# Bootstrap DateTimePicker: Open one datetimepicker at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have an html template with more than one datetimepickers. If I click in the button to open one datetimepicker and after that click in another to open the new one, the first one stays unchanged (it doesn't close). I want to be able to open only one datetimepicker at a time.

Here's a **[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/kmbo576p/396/)**

```
$('#datetimepicker1, #datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
```

This was standard behaviour for bootstrap datetimepicker 2.5 when working with the moment 2.5 (moment-with-langs) but now it seems not to be working like that.

Does anyone have any ideas to workaround this issue?

Note: I'm using Eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker version 3.0.3 with moment 2.8 (moment-with-locales), jQuery 1.9 and Bootstrap 3

What's tricky here is that bootstrap-datetimepicker appends to `<body>` a `<div>` for each datetimepicker initialized that is completely unrelated to its trigger button.

Comment: I've tried several things, even desperate measures like closing all datetimepickers on "open datetimepicker button" click and than trigger a click on the same button to open the specific picker. This didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Joel Lubrano's answer works as intended for preloaded widgets ... it lacks the possibility to work with dynamically generated ones (via JS). Meanwhile, I've managed to work around this issue from inside the component solving both problems by adding one single line.

Inside the component's JS locate the `picker.show` function (around line 1150 depending on version (this in v1.3.1)) ... inside the last else statement of that function, place the following line as the first instruction of that statement.

`$('.picker-open').hide().removeClass('picker-open');`

and that's it. After that you only need to encapsulate the DTP initialization inside a function and call it on document ready and after dynamically generated widgets.

```
function DTPinit(){
    $('.dtp').datetimepicker();
}

$(function(){
    DTPinit();
    $('#dtp_gen').on('click', function(){
        $('body').append('<div class="form-group"><div class="input-group dtp date""><input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" /><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span></div></div>');
        DTPinit();
    });
});
```

Here you have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/kmbo576p/496/) demonstating what I'm describing above. The BS-DTP component is being loaded inside the fiddle JS container for editing purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('.date').datetimepicker();
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Select all elements with the 'date' class
    $('.date').on('dp.show', function() {
        $('.date').not($(this)).each(function() {
            $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
            // $('.date').not($(this)) selects all the .date elements except
            // for the one being shown by the datetimepicker dp.show event.
            // The dp.show event is fired when a new datetimepicker is opened.
            // We use the .data("DateTimePicker") to access the datetimepicker object
            // (we have to use a jQuery each loop in order to access all the 
            // datetimepickers.
            // .hide() -- we hide it.
        });
    });
});
```

That should allow only one datetimepicker to be open at a time.

Comment: Just so I understand properly ... can you elaborate a bit on why this works and why does the data value has to be exactly "DateTimePicker"?

Comment: If you look through the source code (near the bottom) you will see `$.fn.datetimepicker = function (options) {
return this.each(function () {
var $this = $(this),
data = $this.data('DateTimePicker');
if (!data) {
$this.data('DateTimePicker', new DateTimePicker(this, options));
}
});
};`  Which seems to imply that "DateTimePicker" is the key at which the author of the library chose to store the datetimepicker object.  I am by no means a javascript expert, but hopefully that helps answer part of your question.

Comment: As far as why the code works, see my comments above.

Comment: That's better than good. I was just struggling with the "DateTimePicker" there but it's all clear now. Thank you very much. Cheers.

Comment: I again Joel ... I've added another datetimepicker to the equation and now it doesn't work with your approach :/ ... any ideas why? http://jsfiddle.net/kmbo576p/415/

Comment: I'm glad you embraced this challange. Working like a charm now. Thanks!